# Roundcube logo mail-in-a-box

Tags: email, html, webmail

I've installed mail-in-a-box on Ubuntu 14.04 and I can't seem to find how to change Roundcube's logo.
Thank you

Comment: This? https://www.howtoforge.com/community/threads/how-do-i-change-the-roundcube-logo-to-my-own.73836/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To convert [nijave's comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/390127/roundcube-logo-mail-in-a-box#comment695109_390127) into an answer, pulling from [HowtoForge's How do I change the roundcube logo to my own?](https://www.howtoforge.com/community/threads/how-do-i-change-the-roundcube-logo-to-my-own.73836/) -- knowing that I don't have the software available to test this:

Edit the /etc/roundcube/config.inc.php file:

```
// replace Roundcube logo with this image
// specify an URL relative to the document root of this Roundcube installation
// an array can be used to specify different logos for specific template files, '*' for default logo
// for example array("*" => "/images/roundcube_logo.png", "messageprint" => "/images/roundcube_logo_print.png")
$config['skin_logo'] = "/images/roundcube_logo.png";
```

Where you've put the desired image in that path. Note that the path is relative to the Roundcube installation.